# 2002 saturn sl200 car dies withing 2 -3 seconds after starting

Tags: troubleshooting, saturn

Went to start my car one morning for work and it would turn over you could hear the engine running then as soon as you heard it, it would shut off.  My neighbor said it's not the fuel pump (he checked the pressure), he thinks it's the brain.  We replaced it and it is still doing the same thing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like immobilizer. Is anything ok with the key?

Answer (score 1):

Lock and unlock your car using the key buttons two or three times, count to three between presses. Finally open the door with the key buttons, put the key into ignition and turn it to run. If the indicator for the immobiliser stays on, you now know you have an immobiliser fault. You will proberbly have to have your vehicle scanned for any faults, even if the immobiliser resets.

Comment: where and how do I get it scanned and what is the immobiliser?

Comment: Your local repair shop will have a scanner. It is an electronic device used to check out the electronics on a vehicle. It can also be used to operate systems, called bi-directional, to test for correct operation of components. The scanner will report back to the technician by means of codes or wave forms on the systems under test. An immobiliser is part of the electronic circuitry of the vehicles engine micro processor, ECU, which operates to prevent starting of the vehicle unless the key and its correct transponder match the vehicles settings.